# PHP returns different value despite of MySQL query result

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT VALUE FROM int_gtpro.parametrage WHERE namespace = 'taux_vente_usd_htg';
```

The type of the field "value" is medium text.

The MYSQL query returns "{amount: 110.20}".

Now, when I use PHP:

```
<?php

$dbo = new Net_Connection_QueryBuilder();
$queryString = $dbo->select(   
                            "value"
);
$queryString .= $dbo->from("parametrage");
$queryString .= $dbo->where(array("namespace = 'taux_vente_usd_htg'"));
$infos = Net_Connection_Connection::select($queryString);

echo json_encode($infos);
```

and JS

```
$.post('ajax.php?action=getUSDtoHTGrate', {}, function(data) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(data))
                data = JSON.parse(data)
                $('#rate_out > span').text(data.amount);
    })
```

It returns "6" instead of 110.20, why ?

Comment: Is it the same database?

Comment: Yes, it is the same

Comment: `echo json_encode($infos);` prints "{amount: 110.20}" or "{amount: 6}"?

Comment: It prints me other thing: "14"

Comment: the field value is actually the field amount right? please `var_dump($infos) `;

Comment: The var dump prints me also "14"

Comment: please  `var_dump($querystring)`

Comment: It prints me "'SELECT value 
        FROM int_gtpro.parametrage 
        WHERE namespace = 'taux_vente_usd_htg''"

Comment: Please var_dump with $infos = Net_Connection_Connection::select("select 7;"); it should print 7;

Comment: It prints me 15

Comment: You printed $infos while using "select 7;" right and it printed 15? This means it's not actually executing a sql query or it's not returning the result. Try "slct2;" to see if it detects the spelling error